# Spring Boot 3: Batchapplication with modular contexts doesnt start any jobs

Tags: spring-batch

I upgraded to Spring Boot 3 and all of a sudden my batch application doesn't start any jobs when I specify them via `--spring.batch.job.names`.

This is my main class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("path.to.my.repositories")
@EntityScan("path.to.my.entities")
public class MyBatchApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(MyBatchApplication.class, args)));
    }

}
```

This is my config

```java
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)
public class MyModularBatchJobContextConfiguration {
    @Bean
    ApplicationContextFactory getJobAContext() {
        return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(JobAConfig.class);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationContextFactory getJobBContext() {
        return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(JobBConfig.class);
    }
}
```

and `JobA.class` and `JobB.class` basically the same like:

```java
public class JobAConfig {

    private static final String MY_JOB_NAME = "jobA"

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Bean
    public Job jobA(JobRepository jobRepository, Step myStep) {
        return new JobBuilder(MY_JOB_NAME, jobRepository)
                .flow(myStep)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step myStep(JpaTransactionManager transactionManager,
                       JobRepository jobRepository,
                       FlatFileItemReader<MyEntity> reader,
                       ItemProcessor<MyEntity, MyEntity> processor,
                       JpaItemWriter<MyEntity> entityWriter) {
        return new StepBuilder(MY_STEP_NAME, jobRepository)
                .<MyEntity, MyEntity>chunk(10, transactionManager)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(plzOrtEntityWriter)
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .build();
    }

// Reader, Writer, Processor...
```

when i run the jar with `java -jar mybatchapplication.jar --spring.batch.job.names=jobA` nothing happens, the job is not started.

```bash
2023-05-11T22:05:21.823+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] d.f.r.batch.MyBatchApplication: Starting MyBatchApplicationusing Java 17.0.5 with PID 9716 (C:\gits\mygit\batch\target\mybatchapplication.jar started by me in C:\gits\mygit)
2023-05-11T22:05:21.825+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] d.f.r.batch.MyBatchApplication: No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-05-11T22:05:22.112+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.annotation.BatchRegistrar      : Finished Spring Batch infrastructure beans configuration in 6 ms.
2023-05-11T22:05:22.118+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-05-11T22:05:22.149+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 25 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-05-11T22:05:22.571+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-05-11T22:05:22.616+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-05-11T22:05:22.895+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-05-11T22:05:22.995+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Receiver class org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract int getNetworkTimeout()' of interface java.sql.Connection.)
2023-05-11T22:05:22.998+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:file:~/mydb user=SA
2023-05-11T22:05:22.999+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-05-11T22:05:23.016+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2023-05-11T22:05:23.542+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-05-11T22:05:23.552+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-11T22:05:23.588+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2
2023-05-11T22:05:23.613+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2023-05-11T22:05:24.294+02:00  WARN 9716 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.AbstractListenerFactoryBean    : org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor is an interface. The implementing class will not be queried for annotation based listener configurations. If using @StepScope on a @Bean method, be sure to return the implementing class so listener annotations can be used.
2023-05-11T22:05:24.322+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] .c.a.BatchObservabilityBeanPostProcessor : No Micrometer observation registry found, defaulting to ObservationRegistry.NOOP
2023-05-11T22:05:24.358+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] .c.a.BatchObservabilityBeanPostProcessor : No Micrometer observation registry found, defaulting to ObservationRegistry.NOOP
2023-05-11T22:05:24.370+02:00  WARN 9716 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.AbstractListenerFactoryBean    : org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor is an interface. The implementing class will not be queried for annotation based listener configurations. If using @StepScope on a @Bean method, be sure to return the implementing class so listener annotations can be used.
2023-05-11T22:05:24.371+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] .c.a.BatchObservabilityBeanPostProcessor : No Micrometer observation registry found, defaulting to ObservationRegistry.NOOP
2023-05-11T22:05:24.371+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] .c.a.BatchObservabilityBeanPostProcessor : No Micrometer observation registry found, defaulting to ObservationRegistry.NOOP
2023-05-11T22:05:24.395+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] d.f.r.batch.MyBatchApplication: Started MyBatchApplicationin 2.848 seconds (process running for 3.242)
2023-05-11T22:05:24.406+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-11T22:05:24.410+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-05-11T22:05:24.417+02:00  INFO 9716 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Does anybody know whats wrong here?
I also tried with `--spring.batch.job.name=`, no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Spring Boot 3, there is no need for `@EnableBatchProcessing`. If you add it, the auto-configuration of Spring Batch (meta-data tables creation, launching of jobs at startup, etc) will back off. This is mentioned in the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-batch-changes) of Spring Boot 3.

So in your case, if you want to modularize your context, you have two options:

- Either continue using `@EnableBatchProcessing` to benefit from `modular = true`, but in that case you have to manually do what Spring Boot used to previously do (ie initialize the database, run the job at startup, etc).
- Or remove `@EnableBatchProcessing` (to benefit from Boot 3 features as before), but in that case you need to modularize your context manually

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear. I'd probably like to go with the second option, do you know by any chance where I can find an example that shows how to modularize the context manually?

Comment: I don't have an example of that. But if you ask another question and share the code you want to modularize *without* `@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)` then I can try to help you do it.

Comment: Imo this is something that should be contained in the migration guide, but apparently this was not considered to be relevant. Which I don't understand, as modularizing batch contexts is probably something many people do in their batch applications. I'll try to remove `@EnableBatchProcessing(modular=true)`, re-add `@Configuration` to all my batch config classes and give each bean method a unique name (e.g. i have itemReader() in two of my jobs atm), hopefully this already solves the problem. For the time being, thank you for your help :)

Comment: Ok, this didnt work. I opened a new question. Would greatly appreciate any help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76235003/modular-batch-job-contexts-with-spring-batch-5

Comment: `Imo this is something that should be contained in the migration guide`: Your opinion matters to us! How can we address this? Nothing has changed regarding to this in Spring Batch, the behaviour of the annotation and the `modular` attribute are exactly the same. What has changed is the way Spring Boot interprets that annotation. Suggestions are always welcome if we can improve the migration experience in any way. I will check your other question. Thank you.

Comment: Mhh, maybe you guys could add a minimum example to `spring-batch-sample` containing a batch app with 2 jobs and `@EnableBatchProcessing(modular=true)` that shows what has to be configured manually now

Answer (score 0):

In your properties file add:

`spring.batch.job.enabled: true`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help